# stop play video when I'm focus textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, onkeypress

When I keyup spacebar, paly video.
But If I focus on the 'textarea' for writing play video too.
i wanna stop video if i focus on the textarea. help me!

---

```
window.onkeypress = function(e) {

    if (e.srcElement.className.indexOf('dragClass') > -1) { 
        if (e.keyCode === 1300) {
            divWidth = document.getElementById('controlBar').clientWidth;
            if (divWidth < canvas.width)
                scale = divWidth / canvas.width;
            else
                scale = 1;
            curSize += 0;
            ctx.font = curSize + 'px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = curColor;
            ctx.fillText(textBox.value, mouseX / scale, mouseY / scale); 
            videoDiv.removeChild(textBox);
        }
    } else if (e.srcElement.id == 'textArea') {;
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) { 
            $('.play-pause-btn-' + modalId).blur();
            if (vid.paused) {
                vid.play();
                playbtn.style.background = "url(/assets/images/common/btn_pause_black.png) 50% 50% no-repeat";
                loop();
            } else {
                vid.pause();
                playbtn.style.background = "url(/assets/images/common/btn_play_black.png) 50% 50% no-repeat";
            }

        }
        if (e.keyCode === 44) {
            previousframeStep();
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 46) {
            nextframeStep();
        }
    }
```

Here my code.

Comment: `e.keycode === 1300`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "e.srcElement.id" use "e.target.id". Also it would be better if the textArea object had a event listener that triggered to do what you want rather than the window object.
If you are wanting to check via the "id" method you should also have a safety check in there as well, because not all objects have a id property and that will throw a error!

```
if (e.target.id && e.target.id === "textarea")\\then do whatever
```